# What is this resistor - can't find its code

Tags: resistors

Burned out resistor can tell if that's silver or yellow as the multiplier. But neither correspond to a resistor I can find to replace it.

[image: Resistor Colour Bands]

Answer (score 3):

Your resistor is backwards. The color bands are blue-grey-silver-gold. 0.68ohms, +/-5%. 2 or 3W, wirewound.

Comment: Very good. Some comments on the multiplier would be useful for people unaccustomed to below unity multipliers.

Comment: (FTR: You know black: 10⁰=1. Gold: 10⁻¹=.1; silver: 10⁻²=.01 (pink: 10⁻³=.001).)